# Do I need to add both naked and www domain to my heroku app?

Tags: heroku

I am still not clear from the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#dns-setup), if I want my website, say "joe.com" to work on heroku both through the "joe.com" and "www.joe.com" (I am using DNSimple), do I need to have both of them in my app's Domains?

E.g. should my app have both "joe.com" and "www.joe.com" in the Settings/Domains field? Or just the "joe.com"?

The docs say that for apex domains I only need to create a DNSimple Alias... and nothing about adding that apex domain to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add both the www & apex to your application.

In terms of your DNS setup, you can either do it like so:

> joe.com ALIAS {app name}.herokuapp.com
>
> www.joe.com CNAME joe.com

or

> joe.com ALIAS {app name}.herokuapp.com
>
> www.joe.com ALIAS {app name}.herokuapp.com

I would personally go the first method though. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the first approach, with both domains added to heroku app, and it works! (Just took a day to resolve everything correctly).

Comment: If the second works that would be an even better option because an ALIAS does not overwrite MX records like a CNAME does.